# sql - find max value

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with 3 columns: Code, Year, percentage.

I need to return the code with the lowest (minimal) percentage in 2009. After this, I want also the name of the code, that exsist in other table that I made.

I only think using CREATE VIEW, but I prefer not to do so.

Comment: `select top 1 with ties Code  from yourtable where year = 2009 order by percentage`

Comment: @Oded It alwayes gives me problems that view already define in my DB. I read about this is the web, and I solve it. But from time to time, the problem repeat.

Comment: Are ties possible?  Can two codes in a year have the same percentage?

Comment: Why Title `Finding MAX` since you are asking for `MIN`?

Answer (score 5):

```
Select table.code, table.year, table.percentage, othertable.name
from table
inner join othertable  on table.FKId = othertable.PKid
where year = 2009 
  and percentage = 
  (select min(percentage) 
   from table 
   where year = 2009)
```

Updated to include the othertable... since we don't have names.

UPDATED
 Now that we have table names...  Updated 3rd time now that I know year is string.

```
Select E.Code, C.Name 
From dbo.Exam E
inner join dbo.Course C
  ON E.Code = C.Code  
Where E.Year = '2009' and --<-- PROBLEM LIKELY HERE year was string not int.
 E.Fail = (select MIN(E2.Fail) 
                  from dbo.Exam E2 where E2.Year = '2009') --<--Don't forget here too.
```

From comments: sample Data:

```
 INSERT INTO Exam VALUES(333,'2009',40) 
 INSERT INTO Exam VALUES(333,'2009',20) 
 INSERT INTO Exam VALUES(555,'2009',19) 
 INSERT INTO Exam VALUES(444,'2009',19) 
 INSERT INTO Exam VALUES(777,'2009',23) 
 INSERT INTO Exam VALUES(333,'2009',0) 
 INSERT INTO Course VALUES(111,'Name1',5) 
 INSERT INTO Course VALUES(333,'Name2',5) 
 INSERT INTO Course VALUES(444,'Name3',6) 
 INSERT INTO Course VALUES(555,'Name4',3) 
 INSERT INTO Course VALUES(777,'Name5',3) 
 INSERT INTO Course VALUES(999,'Name6',6)
```

Assumption is result should be 
Name2, 5

Comment: Exactly what I was going to post. +1 for sniping me :p

Comment: Should still look up the name for the code, but that's a simple join

Comment: @xQbert whats wrong with `select code, min(percentage) from table where year=2009 group by code`

Comment: @RoyiNamir - It doesn't work. It will find the minimum percentage for each code.

Comment: nods..  only can return 1 value.  not 3. if 2009, 2010, 2011 exist I only want 2009; thus group by isn't needed.

Comment: I did it, It still not working. I wrote:

Select dbo.Exam.Code, dbo.Course.Name
From dbo.Exam inner join dbo.Course
ON dbo.Exam.Code = dbo.Course.Code
Where dbo.Exam.Year = 2009 and dbo.Exam.Fail = (select MIN (dbo.Exam.Fail) from dbo.Exam where dbo.Exam.Year = 2009)

It doesnt return something.

Comment: look at your join. how do exam and course relate I doubt it's by exam.code and course.code.  It's probably by exam.courseCode = course.code or something like that.

Comment: I guess I need to see some sample data then.  Because the original post would have returned the lowest percentage  name for  2009.  Logically it doesn't make sense to me that an Exam.Code = Course.Code.  So can you show some sample data from both tables?  or is exam.year not a int? is it a string and 2009 needs '' around it?

Comment: YES:
INSERT INTO Exam VALUES(333,'2009',40)
INSERT INTO Exam VALUES(333,'2009',20)
INSERT INTO Exam VALUES(555,'2009',19)
INSERT INTO Exam VALUES(444,'2009',19)
INSERT INTO Exam VALUES(777,'2009',23)
INSERT INTO Exam VALUES(333,'2009',0)

INSERT INTO Course VALUES(111,'Name1',5)
INSERT INTO Course VALUES(333,'Name2',5)
INSERT INTO Course VALUES(444,'Name3',6)
INSERT INTO Course VALUES(555,'Name4',3)
INSERT INTO Course VALUES(777,'Name5',3)
INSERT INTO Course VALUES(999,'Name6',6)

Comment: Yep, year is string in your example. I've corrected my answer to wrap 2009 in tics so where year = '2009' your earlier post needs the same correction. unless SQL server does an implicit conversion from in to string and vice-versa.

Comment: xQbert: Sorry, but is still doesn't work. even If I insert ''. BTW, it's written in the SQL: Year(PK,FK,int, not null). So how its string?

Comment: your insert statement has values (444,'2009',19) implying '2009' is a string.  are you getting any error? if so what is it. cause I'm at a loss.  Do it in stages try `select MIN(E2.Fail) 
                  from dbo.Exam E2 where E2.Year = 2009` first. does it return 0?

Comment: Nothing.. It returns empty table.

Comment: Well only 2 things I can think of 1) your insert statements show the data type for year as string.  which is odd.  so I don't know how the E2.Year = 2009 is being evaluated. We can remove the where clause and that will tell me if there's a conversion problem on the year to 2009.  so try `select MIN(E2.Fail) from dbo.Exam E2` if you get results then your E2 year datatype vs data entry is off. and I'm not sure how to fix it. if we don't get results then I'm at a total loss.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `group by` to find the lowest percentage for a year, and then join back to the main tables to find the corresponding other columns:

```
select  *
from    CodeYearPercTbl cyp
join    CodeTbl c
on      c.Code = cyp.Code
join    (
        select  Year
        ,       min(Percentage) as MinPerc
        from    CodeYearPercTbl
        group by
                Year
        ) as filter
on      filter.Year = cyp.Year
        and filter.MinPerc = cyp.Percentage
where   cyp.Year = 2009
```

Answer (score 0):

Table-1 : Code,Year,Percentage
Table-2 : Code,CodeName

```
select T1.Code,T2.CodeName,T1.Percentage from
(
     select TOP 1 Code,Percentage 
     from Table-1 
     where Year = '2009' 
     order by Percentage asc
) T1  inner join Table-2 T2 on T1.Code = T2.Code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.Code, c.Name 
from  YourTable a inner join AnotherTable c on a.Code = c.Code 
where a.Percentage = (select MIN(Percentage) 
                      from YourTable  b where b.Year = '2009'
                     )
```